# Python: create a function decorator that memoizes a function

Tags: python

What I have to do in this function is to create a local table and wrap the function with a lookup into the table and store of the result if it needs to be computed. This should work with any function as long as it is only called with hashable arguments. Make sure you support any number of positional and keyword arguments. (we cant use global table)

This will be used like:

```
@memoize
def fib(n):
    if n > 1:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    else:
        return n
```

Can someone show me some hints>?

Comment: That's one of the standard examples of decorators, did you even bother doing any research?

Comment: [Did you try Google?](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+memoization+decorator)

Comment: Two seconds of googling gives https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize. How much research did you say you did?

Comment: If you are on Python 3 you can use [`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache). Or is this some kind of homework ... ?

Comment: "Make sure you support any number of positional and keyword arguments." When you're rewriting your assignment into a question, it might be a good idea to rewrite the parts that make is sound like you're planning to grade us on it, because most of us don't want to take a class from you.

Comment: It is in the standard library, But we are asked to do it different way

Answer (score 1):

```
def memoize(f):
    local_table = create_a_local_table()
    @functools.wraps
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        assert isinstance(len(args), numbers.Number)
        assert isinstance(len(kwargs), numbers.Number)
        return lookup_into_the_table_and_store_of_the_result_if_it_needs_to_be_computed(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Implementing those two functions is left as an exercise for the reader. Note that the second one will have to be a local function within `memoize`, unless you give it some other way to access `local_table`.

Also note that some of the literal translation of your question is unnecessary.